# Coldfusion Session.preferenceObject concept

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, coldbox

In a coldfusion application I noticed some getter & setter like object.

```
 <cfset Session.preferenceObject.setHomePage_Title('#HomePage_Details#')>
 <textarea name="HomePage_Details" cols="50" rows="4" scroll="no">#Session.preferenceObject.getHomePage_Details()#</textarea>
```

it is working fine.I can save the value in DB also.Similarly I tried with Customer_Detais.

```
<cfset Session.preferenceObject.setCustomer_Details('#Customer_Details#')>
<textarea name="Customer_Details" cols="50" rows="4" scroll="no">#Session.preferenceObject.getCustomer_Details()#</textarea>
```

But it is not working.Can anyone help me on this concept? I can't understand this coldfusion concept.

Comment: Are you sure about part of the variable name. Is it `Detais` or `Details`?

Comment: "But it is not working" - Tell us *how* it is not working. Do you get an error? What does the error say?

Comment: @Pankaj spelling mistake.Anyway it should work right?

Comment: @beloitdavisja : We can save the textarea value in db without any insert query.(I can't able to track the method of saving operation) in case of HomePage_Details..But no insertion for Customer_Details. No errors getting.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tmt-calendar/source/browse/trunk/client/Application.cfc?r=46 ..use this link as an reference.

Comment: Use `<cfdump var="#Session.preferenceObject#">` to inspect the component and its methods. As long as you do not provide any real information, nobody can help you here.

Comment: If setHomePage_Title() works, try to understand how it works, then you'll find the answer to your question about setCustomer_Details(). "Don't Imitate... Understand!"

Answer (score 0):

I think, you only can use getCustomer_Detais() if exists a setter, like setCustomer_Detais("value")...

In your case, only exists a setHomePage_Title setter...